# How to use ExcelDNA developed XLL from C# without Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

we have built XLL in C# using ExcelDna as described in https://excel-dna.net/ --- everything works when tested from Excel.

We would like to be able to use this XLL in other .NET projects  -- in other words, how do we "host" this XLL from .NET?   The XLL does not appear to be a 
valid .NET assembly -- so I cannot add it as a .NET reference to other projects

Is it done through ExcelDna.Integration dll somehow (which IS a .net assembly)?

Thank you

Comment: What is your goal exactly? What is inside the XLL that you want to use from a C# application?

Comment: Lets say its a bunch of C# classes that do financial calculations -- I would like to be able to use them from different in-house .NET programs

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Excel-DNA is just a glue between Excel and .NET assemblies.

If you want to reuse functionality that is inside a .NET assembly that is being loaded by an Excel-DNA Add-In (i.e. `XLL`), then you don't need the `XLL` for anything... All you need is the .NET assembly that the `XLL` is loading - Add a reference to **that** in your .NET application and you're good to go... Just like you would do with any other class library.

In other words, inside your `.dna` file that is used by Excel-DNA to determine what to load, you have something that looks like this:

```
<DnaLibrary Name="Your Add-In" RuntimeVersion="v4.0">
  <ExternalLibrary Path="YourAssembly.dll" ExplicitExports="false" ... />
</DnaLibrary>
```

`YourAssembly.dll` is already the .NET assembly that contains the functions that are exposed to Excel-DNA.

---

More importantly, if you know you're going to have different .NET "clients" for your functions, then you should design for that, isolate the reusable functions in a dedicated assembly, and have your Excel-DNA assembly reference that, and expose the functions to Excel, instead of forcing clients to depend on Excel-DNA assemblies.

e.g.

- C# Class Library `Functions.dll` (does not reference anything)
- C# Class Library `ExcelAddIn.dll` (references `Functions.dll`)
- C# App `MyCsApp.exe` (references `Functions.dll`)
- C# Class Library `FunctionsComInterop.dll` (references `Functions.dll`)
- C++ App `MyCppApp.exe` (calls `FunctionsComInterop.dll`)
- etc.

[image: diagram]

In the example above:

- `Functions.dll` does **not** reference any Excel-DNA assembly and it does **not** expose anything via to COM. It should have as little dependencies as possible (ideally none!)
- `ExcelAddIn.dll` makes the bridge to Excel-DNA and exposes Excel functions that can be called by Excel through Excel-DNA. These functions simply forward calls to the `Functions.dll` assembly... Nothing more.
- `FunctionsComInterop.dll` makes the bridge to C++ and exposes COM functions that can be called by the C++ app. These functions simply forward calls to the `Functions.dll` assembly... Nothing more.

Comment: Thank you.  What if the calling language is C++ and I want to use COM?  How do we "pull" this (or these) DLL/XLLs into the C++ client ?  thanks

Comment: In that case, you'd have to expose the C# functions via COM Interop and have the C++ call your assembly. I'd recommend creating a separate class library that does just that - exposes functions via COM, and forwards the call to the main C# assembly. You're effectively building an API for a C++ client, so you should be explicit about it and have control over the interface